# Firebase flutter instance.getInitialMessage() returning null (IOS) when the notification is opened in terminated state

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am encountering an issue with redirecting users to a specific screen in my iOS application developed in Flutter when they click on a push notification received through Firebase Cloud Messaging. Here's the scenario:

In my Flutter iOS application, push notifications are received via Firebase Messaging. Upon clicking a notification, the user should be redirected to a particular screen. The data for these notifications is being sent from a Node.js server using the Firebase Legacy API.

Here's the code snippet for sending notifications from the Node.js server:

```js
const response = await fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${server_key}`,
            },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            registration_ids: tokens,
            notification:{
              title:title,
              body:body
            },
            data:{
              // ...some data
            },
            content_available: true
          })
        })
```

The issue arises when the application is terminated: the `message` retrieved from `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {})` returns `null`. Consequently, I am unable to access `message.data`, preventing the redirection of the user to the specific screen.

I have tried placing the `getInitialMessage` function in various locations, such as `main.dart` or `bottom_navigation.dart`, but it consistently returns null.

However, there are some exceptions: occasionally, when the app is opened from a notification after some delay, the notification is received, and redirection works as expected. But this behavior is inconsistent.

I am confused by this behavior. Could there be any restrictions from the iOS side on receiving payload when the app is terminated? If so, are there any alternative methods to achieve the same functionality? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.